# While building sign-in with twitter on safari for iphone, how can I use the accounts already added in my settings

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, safari

Im trying to build sign-in with twitter on my web application, which redirects to twitter for sign-in shows app permissions page etc and comes back to my application after authentication, what I actually want to do is, if I have twitter app installed, and Im signed into it, I want to use that information in my web application running on safari. 
How do I do that in case it is possible.